# extra file acces or lots of realloc

Tags: c, memory-management, file-io

I am writing a function which needs to parse a config file line by line.

I basically have 3 ways to go from here, I am at the stage where I read a line into memory:

1. read amount of character in a line, `fseek()` back to beginning of line, `malloc()` buffer, read line into memory
2. read characters in the line and `realloc()` for each addition character
3. make a 'guess' of a reasonable line length and only `realloc()` once that is exceeded.

Time is not really important at this stage so whether 1ms or half a second is doesn`t really matter but I would like to have the solution that is considered best.

In the past I have used solution 1 since I didn't really like calling `realloc()` maybe hundreds of times.

What is considered best practice?

e/

some further explanation:

my config file looks something like this

key=value #comment

what I during reading is replace the `=` character with a `\0` character and track the offsets. Then I `strcompare()` the line to configuration tags I am looking for and once I have found a matching configuration tag I move the value to the beginning of the array and do post-processing(`atoi()`, `strtoull()` those kind of things) and put it into another variable. After that I free my read line and go to the next-line.

while I do while I read characters. I skip whitespaces and everything after a `#` won`t be read into memory. So my entire key=value string is <64 bytes in 99% of the cases.

Comment: guess a reasonable line length `realloc` geometrically, and *reuse* the same buffer for further line reading. in the end your buffer will be sufficient for the longest line + slack. Since you have not elaborated on the storage requirements *post*-line parsing this approach is admittedly speculative. (Example where this would *not* work: the buffer is used to persist the tokens after parsing and thus buffer-reuse on future lines isn't an option).

Comment: I have added some more info

Comment: note that there is a POSIX function called `getline` which basically does what WhozCraig suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of allocating a small buffer and reallocting frequently, allocate a large buffer and reallocate to the exact size needed. Perhaps something like this would work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *getinput ( ) {
    char *input;

    input = malloc ( 1000); // allocate a large buffer
    fgets (input, 1000, stdin);
    // may need to set a '\0' somewhere in input...
    input = realloc ( input, strlen(input) + 1); // realloc to exact size
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    char *output[10];
    int counter = 0;

    while ( counter < 10) {
        output[counter] = getinput();
        printf ( "%s\n", output[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
    counter = 0;
    while ( counter < 10) {
        printf ( "\t%s\n", output[counter]);
        free ( output[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the size of the input data may turn out to be large, I use a technique similar to the [Exponential Backoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).

An approximate algorithm is:

1. allocate a small buffer
2. read data while there is some space in the buffer
3. if there buffer is full and there is some data to read, double the size of the buffer (via `realloc()`)
4. goto step 2

If you read the whole file at once, then just append all incoming data to the end of the buffer.

If you read one line at a time, then use `fgets()` in a loop, like this:

1. allocate a buffer
2. set `buffer[size - 1] = 0xFF`;
3. `fgets(buffer, size, fp);`
4. if `buffer[size - 1] == '\0'` then the buffer is full, `realloc()` it and goto step 2

This approach is sensible when you expect to get arbitrary large lines, for example, someone will decide to put some base64-encoded data to the configuration file. If that is not a case, I usually try to keep things as simple as:

1. allocate a fixed-size buffer that likely fits any line in the file
2. try to read a line, if it didn't fit to the buffer, then `abort()`

In fact, such approach tends to produce less bugs than any buffer reallocation, KISS in its beauty.

Comment: A variation on doubling the size of a string buffer when more space is needed is to instead `realloc` and add some constant length. This can be preferable when you are storing multiple lines and your system is memory constrained.

Comment: realloc and malloc are expensive (timewise) calls.  So run a utility (there are plenty available) that will return the length of the longest line (in linux/unix that would be 'wc -L') and malloc that length+1 once and use it forever.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

First read in the whole file into a buffer, just check the size first er.g. stat() and then read it all in.

Once you have the whole file contents in a buffer you can manipulate it to your hearts content.